# How do I have Multiple Conditional formats on a single cell in excel 2013 without using a macro

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to know how to make a cell go blank (i.e. stay white) if either one of the source cells for a conditional format is blank.
I have two sets of data:
Column A: protein on a weekly basis across the year (52 data points).
Column B: protein:fat ratio on a weekly basis across the year (52 data points).

Column C will either fill in Red or Green depending on whether these conditions are met.

If `protein >= 25 AND protein:fat ratio >=5`, then green, otherwise red.

If `protein >=26 AND protein:fat ratio >=4.5`, then green, otherwise red.

I'm new to all this, so I made the default colour of the cells red, and if the above conditions were met, the cell would turn green.

I used the following formula: `=OR(AND(a3>=25,b3>=5),(AND(a3>=26,b3>=4.5)))` Where `a` was protein and `b` was protein:fat ratio.

However, I don't have a complete data set and there is missing information. I would like the cell to go blank if either one of columns A or B have no data. is there a way to incorporate that into what I already have to achieve what I need, or is there a more elegant way of doing what I need to do?
Any guidance anyone can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have multiple rules for each cell in conditional formatting.  You go to manage rules under conditional formatting and add a new rule.  The equation would be `=OR(A3=0,B3=0)`. The format then would be white fill.

Answer (score 0):

An additional CF rule as suggested by @Scott should work but it may be simpler to filter ColumnA to select blanks and remove the red fill from the ColumnC cells for those rows and then repeat with filtering of ColumnB. The green formatting is only triggered by values that are a positive number so will not be triggered for a row with blank cells in either or both columns.